# Datestring formatting

Tags: javascript, date

I've been working a lot with dates and various capacities for the past month.  I can't seem to find any decent documentation on working with dates in javascript.

for example: [PHPfreaks](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/working-with-dates-in-php) has a wonderful explanation of any and all date() functions.

I just want to make sure I am properly utilizing all of the date object's methods.

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp) has the best explanation that i've found.

So i'm taking the opportunity to utilize SO -

1. What are the methods attached to the date object? (found @ [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp))
2. If you are inclined, list any interesting or useful scripts with the date obj (including odd behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) link to be helpful.  I think it does list all date methods, including getMonth().

One odd behavior thing to take note of is that getMonth returns the month in terms 0-11, where getDate returns day of the month 1-31, so when using getMonth you need to know to add 1 if you want the month in terms 1-12.

Comment: aha! I had a feeling I wasn't viewing the full date Object description in w3schools.  very good.

Comment: I edited my question to include the proper w3schools link.  thanks again.  I'd still like to check out some interesting scripts/odd functionalities w/ the date object =)

Answer (score 2):

This is a good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date